# Jasmine test not working with ng-content ngModel

Tags: angular, jasmine

We have a component that we use to wrap our input fields.  It works great but the Jasmine tests do not.  I have narrowed down the what is causing the test to fail but not sure why or how to correct.

This component has a bunch of functionality (translation, accessibility, adds required indicator, etc) that I have stripped out of this version / explanation because they are not important to the problem at hand. So, the component now just basically turns itself red when the field is in error.

[image]

Here is the stripped down component:

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlDirective, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-control-group',
  templateUrl: './my-control-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-control-group.component.css']
})
export class MyControlGroupComponent  {

  @ContentChild('inputElement')
  private inputElement: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  private control: AbstractControlDirective | AbstractControl;


  constructor() { }


  /* This method returns true of the field is in error */
  private isInputFieldInError(): boolean {

      if (this.control && this.control.errors) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }

  }

}
```

Its template

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': isInputFieldInError()}">
      <label class="control-label">Test Field</label>
      <div class="input-container">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
</div>
```

A working usage example is like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm"  novalidate>

    <my-control-group [control]="sampleName">
        <input #inputElement name="sampleName" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="sample.name" required #sampleName="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
    </my-control-group>

</form>
```

And the test spec:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlDirective, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';


import { MyControlGroupComponent } from './my-control-group.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-required-field',
  template: `
<form #myForm="ngForm"  novalidate>
    <my-control-group [control]="sampleName" label="Required field">
        <input #inputElement name="sampleName" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="sample.name" required #sampleName="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
    </my-control-group>
</form>
  `
})
class ContentProjectionComponent {

  private sample = { name : ''};

}



describe('MyControlGroupComponent', () => {
  let component: ContentProjectionComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContentProjectionComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyControlGroupComponent, ContentProjectionComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContentProjectionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    let formGroupDE: DebugElement;
    let formGroupHTML: HTMLElement;

    formGroupDE = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div'));
    formGroupHTML = formGroupDE.nativeElement;
    expect(formGroupHTML.className).toContain("has-error");

  });
});
```

So, the problem is when I debug my tests the field never thinks it is in error.  In other words this.control.errors array is always null even though I have marked the field it wraps as required and the field is empty.

What fixes it?  If I remove my form tags from the template I am testing with like this:

```
      template: `
        <my-control-group [control]="sampleName" label="Required field">
            <input #inputElement name="sampleName" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="sample.name" required #sampleName="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
        </my-control-group>
      `
```

NOTE: You may wonder why I need the form tag anyway - it is required for other functionality that I stripped out of this example.

When debugging the test, I look at this.control WITHOUT the form tag, I can see the required validator in the array rawValidators list and the errors array is populated.  WITH the form tag, there are no validators in that list and the errors array is always null.

Oddly enough this functionality works (as does the rest of what I stripped out) in live stuff.